# Styling with Tailwind CSS

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I'm using Tailwindcss to style my forms but when I try to submit and catch errors for required fields, the size on input fields increases.

**Form code**

```
 <Formik
                    initialValues={userData.signup}
                    onSubmit={submitData}
                    validationSchema={signupSchema}
                >
                    {({ values, errors, touched, handleChange, handleSubmit }) => {
                        return (
                            <>
                                <Form className="grid grid-cols-2 gap-3" onSubmit={handleSubmit} id="form">

                                    <div className="relative flex w-full flex-wrap items-stretch mb-3">

                                        <span className="z-10 leading-snug font-normal absolute text-center text-gray-400 bg-transparent rounded text-base items-center justify-center w-8 pl-3 py-3">
                                            <i className="fas fa-user-circle"></i>
                                        </span>

                                        <input
                                            className={
                                                `${touched.name && errors.name ?
                                                    "form-input border py-3 border-red-400 placeholder-gray-400 text-gray-700 relative rounded text-sm  w-full pl-10" :
                                                    "form-input border py-3 border-gray-400 placeholder-gray-400 text-gray-700 relative rounded text-sm focus:border-green-200 w-full pl-10"}`
                                            }
                                            type="text"
                                            name="name"
                                            placeholder="Name"
                                            value={values.name}
                                            onChange={handleChange}

                                        />
                                        <span className="text-red-400 self-center">{touched.name && errors.name}</span>
                                    </div>

                                    <div className="relative flex w-full flex-wrap items-stretch mb-3">

                                        <span className="z-10 leading-snug font-normal absolute text-center text-gray-400 bg-transparent rounded text-base items-center justify-center w-8 pl-3 py-3">
                                            <i className="fas fa-envelope"></i>
                                        </span>

                                        <input
                                            className={
                                                `${touched.email && errors.email ?
                                                    "form-input border py-3 border-red-400 placeholder-gray-400 text-gray-700 relative rounded text-sm  w-full pl-10" :
                                                    "form-input border py-3 border-gray-400 placeholder-gray-400 text-gray-700 relative rounded text-sm focus:border-green-200 w-full pl-10"}`
                                            }
                                            type="email"
                                            name="email"
                                            placeholder="Email"
                                            value={values.email}
                                            onChange={handleChange}
                                        />
                                        <span className="text-red-400 self-center">{touched.email && errors.email}</span>

                                    </div>

                                    <div className="relative flex w-full flex-wrap items-stretch mb-3">

                                        <span className="z-10 leading-snug font-normal absolute text-center text-gray-400 bg-transparent rounded text-base items-center justify-center w-8 pl-3 py-3">
                                            <i className="fas fa-phone"></i>
                                        </span>

                                        <input
                                            className={
                                                `${touched.phoneNumber && errors.phoneNumber ?
                                                    "form-input border py-3 border-red-400 placeholder-gray-400 text-gray-700 relative rounded text-sm  w-full pl-10" :
                                                    "form-input border py-3 border-gray-400 placeholder-gray-400 text-gray-700 relative rounded text-sm focus:border-green-200 w-full pl-10"}`
                                            }
                                            type="text"
                                            name="phoneNumber"
                                            placeholder="Phone number"
                                            value={values.phoneNumber}
                                            onChange={handleChange}
                                        />
                                        <span className="text-red-400 self-center">{touched.phoneNumber && errors.phoneNumber}</span>

                                    </div>

                                    <div className="relative flex w-full flex-wrap items-stretch mb-3">

                                        <span className="z-10 leading-snug font-normal absolute text-center text-gray-400 bg-transparent rounded text-base items-center justify-center w-8 pl-3 py-3">
                                            <i className="fas fa-lock"></i>
                                        </span>
                                        <input
                                            className={
                                                `${touched.password && errors.password ?
                                                    "form-input border py-3 border-red-400 placeholder-gray-400 text-gray-700 relative rounded text-sm  w-full pl-10" :
                                                    "form-input border py-3 border-gray-400 placeholder-gray-400 text-gray-700 relative rounded text-sm focus:border-green-200 w-full pl-10"}`
                                            }
                                            type="password"
                                            name="password"
                                            placeholder="Password"
                                            value={values.password}
                                            onChange={handleChange}
                                        />
                                        <span className="text-red-400 self-center">{touched.password && errors.password}</span>

                                    </div>

                                    {/* <div className="relative flex w-full flex-wrap items-stretch mb-3">

                                        <span className="z-10 leading-snug font-normal absolute text-center text-gray-400 bg-transparent rounded text-base items-center justify-center w-8 pl-3 py-3">
                                            <i className="fas fa-lock"></i>
                                        </span>
                                        <input
                                            className={
                                                `${touched.confirmPassword && errors.confirmPassword ?
                                                    "form-input border py-3 border-red-400 placeholder-gray-400 text-gray-700 relative rounded text-sm  w-full pl-10" :
                                                    "form-input border py-3 border-gray-400 placeholder-gray-400 text-gray-700 relative rounded text-sm focus:border-green-200 w-full pl-10"}`
                                            }
                                            type="password"
                                            name="confirmPassword"
                                            placeholder="Confirm Password"
                                            value={values.confirmPassword}
                                            onChange={handleChange}
                                        />
                                        <span className="text-red-400 self-center">{touched.confirmPassword && errors.confirmPassword}</span>

                                    </div> */}

                                </Form>
                                <SignupBtn type="submit" form="form"> Sign Up </SignupBtn>
                                <SocialBtns />
                            </>
                        )
                    }}
                </Formik>
```

**Form before error highlighting using Formik**
[image]

**Form after error highlighting using Formik**

This is the code  I used to style the forms.

[image]

Am I missing anything here? Thanks

Comment: Can you add the code used to style the forms? Error messages are probably in the same grid block as the fields, and therefore take up space and force the fields to shrink.

Comment: Please accept an answer to others know the question is solved

Answer (score 1):

Remove `flex` from the button container...

```
<div class="relative w-full flex-wrap mb-3">
     <button class="py-2 px-4 bg-green-500 text-white font-semibold rounded-lg hover:bg-green-700 w-full">
       Sign Up
     </button>
</div>
```

[Codeply](https://codeply.com/p/UgPU3XXoui)

Comment: Hey @Zim, sorry but your suggestion didn't help. The real answer was to add `max-w-xs` class to the form containing the input fields. Thanks anyways.